# How to loop data in PHP Excel and dynamic column & row

Tags: php, excel

```
$sheet = $this->phpExcel->getActiveSheet();
   // header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    //header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="your_name.xlsx"');
    //header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'keterangan');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B1', '8');
    $sheet->setCellValue('C1', '9');
    $sheet->setCellValue('D1', '10');
    $sheet->setCellValue('E1', '11');
    $sheet->setCellValue('F1', '12');
    $sheet->setCellValue('G1', '13');
    $sheet->setCellValue('H1', '14');
    $sheet->setCellValue('I1', '15');
    $sheet->setCellValue('J1', '16');
    $sheet->setCellValue('K1', '17');
    $sheet->setCellValue('L1', '18');
    $sheet->setCellValue('M1', '19');
    $sheet->setCellValue('N1', '20');
    $sheet->setCellValue('O1', '21');
    $sheet->setCellValue('P1', '22');
    $sheet->setCellValue('Q1', '23');
    $sheet->setCellValue('R1', '24');
    $sheet->setCellValue('S1', '1');
    $sheet->setCellValue('T1', '2');
    $sheet->setCellValue('U1', '3');
    $sheet->setCellValue('V1', '4');
    $sheet->setCellValue('W1', '5');
    $sheet->setCellValue('X1', '7');
    $sheet->setCellValue('Y1', '6');

    // $sheet->setCellValue('G1', 'Saldo');
    $i = 2;

    foreach ($data as $idx) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $i, $idx->name);
        $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $i, $idx->kiln_detail);
        //$sheet->setCellValue('C' . $i,$idx->);
        //$col='A';
    }

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->phpExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('a.xlsx');
}
```

Result $data this is

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => BINGKAI
            [kiln_detail] => 1
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 4
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [20] => 
            [21] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [JML_JAM] => 6
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => BISUL / BENTOL
            [kiln_detail] => 1
            [8] => 
            [9] => 3
            [10] => 4
            [11] => 
            [12] => 4
            [13] => 
            [14] => 3
            [15] => 3
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [20] => 
            [21] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [JML_JAM] => 6
        )
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to increment `$i` inside your loop?

Comment: Yes sir,i think $i use to dynamic row,but not work

Comment: Well why aren't you incrementing `$i` inside the loop? It should work if you try it!

Comment: What are you actually trying to get here?

Comment: try code $x = 2;
        $row=1;
        foreach ($data as $idx) {
            $col='A';
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($timez); $i++) {
                $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $x, $idx->name);
                $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $x, $idx->$timez[$i]);
            }
            $x++;
        }

Comment: but how to dynamicly A,B,C, etc

Comment: [$column = 'A'; for($c = 0; $c <= 128; $c++) { echo $column; $column++; }](https://3v4l.org/snsDR)

Comment: hi you can help me, i have problem download excel ,file not work  message open file extension not valid     mycode   $objPHPExcel = new Excel();

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition:    attachment;filename="item_list.xlsx"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');

Comment: Wrong `content type` header for an `xlsx` file; `xlsx` content type is __"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"__ as shown in [01simple-download-xlsx.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/01simple-download-xlsx.php)